go lang net/http request pattern is not working /task/{id}/
I''ve no idea why, but the example code of new feature of net/http from 1.22 is not working for me.
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "runtime"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(runtime.Version())
    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    mux.HandleFunc("GET /path/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Fprint(w, "got path\n")
    })

    mux.HandleFunc("/task/{id}/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        id := r.PathValue("id")
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "handling task with id=%v\n", id)
    })

    http.ListenAndServe("localhost:8090", mux)
}

I always get 404 not found:
$ curl localhost:8090/path/                                        
404 page not found
$ curl -X POST localhost:8090/path/                                
404 page not found
$ curl localhost:8090/task/f0cd2e/                                 
404 page not found

instead of
$ curl localhost:8090/path/
got path

$ curl -X POST localhost:8090/path/
Method Not Allowed

$ curl localhost:8090/task/f0cd2e/
handling task with id=f0cd2e

What I do wrong? Ggolang version is 1.23.0

The solution is...
I had to add a go 1.23.0 into go.mod.
